# How-to figure out if an action method has a HttpPost attributte?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How-to figure out if an action method has a HttpPost attributte ?

For example in the action filter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470194.aspx) to get attributes applied to the action. Both ActionExecutingContext and ActionExecutedContext expose a property called ActionDescriptor allowing you to get an instance of ActionDescriptor class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use reflection to see if an action have the HttpPostAttribute. 
Assuming your method is something similar:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
   //my code
}
```

you can do the test with this:

```
  var controller = GetMyController();
  var type = controller.GetType();
  var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("MyAction", new Type[1] { typeof(MyViewModel) });
  var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpPostAttribute), true);
  Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Any());
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way that I found is the following:

```
var controller = GetMyController();
var type = controller.GetType();
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("MyAction", new Type[1] { typeof(MyViewModel) });
bool isHttpGetAttribute = methodInfo.CustomAttributes.Where(x=>x.AttributeType.Name == "HttpGetAttribute").Count() > 0
```

I hope this helps.

Happy coding.